# Cast string to float is not supported - Denoising Autoencoder for time series data

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am trying to build a denoising autoencoder for time series data. But I am getting, "Cast string to float is not supported" when I try to train the model.

The data that I have used has the following shape:

```
print(np.shape(noisy_samples))
print(np.shape(samples))
```

Output:

> (98, 8000, 2) (98, 8000, 2)

Data type has been changed to numpy array:

```
data_noisy=np.array(noisy_samples)
data_pure=np.array(samples)
print(type(data_pure))
print(type(data_noisy))
```

Output:

> <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Autoencoder Model:

```
import tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, save_model, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, Conv1DTranspose, Input, MaxPooling1D, Flatten, Dense, Reshape, UpSampling1D
from tensorflow.keras.constraints import max_norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

batch_size = 5
no_epochs = 5
train_test_split = 0.3
validation_split = 0.2
verbosity = 1
max_norm_value = 2.0
input_sig = Input(batch_shape=(1,8000,2))

x = Conv1D(16, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(input_sig) 
#x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(2, padding="same")(x)
x = Conv1D(1, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(x) 
#x = BatchNormalization()(x)
encoded = MaxPooling1D(2, padding="same")(x) 

encoder = Model(input_sig, encoded)


x = Conv1D(1, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(encoded) 
#x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = UpSampling1D(2)(x) 
x = Conv1D(16, 2, activation='relu', padding="same")(x) 
#x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = UpSampling1D(2)(x) 
decoded = Conv1D(2, 3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x) 
model = Model(input_sig, decoded)
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.fit(data_noisy, data_pure, epochs = no_epochs, batch_size =batch_size )
```

Output:

> Model: "model_1"
> _________________________________________________________________ Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
> ================================================================= input_1 (InputLayer)         [(1, 8000, 2)]            0
> _________________________________________________________________ conv1d (Conv1D)              (1, 8000, 16)             112
> _________________________________________________________________ max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D) (1, 4000, 16)             0
> _________________________________________________________________ conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (1, 4000, 1)              49
> _________________________________________________________________ max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (1, 2000, 1)              0
> _________________________________________________________________ conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (1, 2000, 1)              4
> _________________________________________________________________ up_sampling1d (UpSampling1D) (1, 4000, 1)              0
> _________________________________________________________________ conv1d_3 (Conv1D)            (1, 4000, 16)             48
> _________________________________________________________________ up_sampling1d_1 (UpSampling1 (1, 8000, 16)             0
> _________________________________________________________________ conv1d_4 (Conv1D)            (1, 8000, 2)              98
> ================================================================= Total params: 311 Trainable params: 311 Non-trainable params: 0
> _________________________________________________________________ Epoch 1/5
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 46 model.summary()
> 47 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
> ---> 48 model.fit(data_noisy, data_pure, epochs = no_epochs, batch_size =batch_size )
> 49
>
> 6 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py
> in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
> 58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
> 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
> ---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
> 61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
> 62     if name is not None:
>
> UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported     [[node
> model_1/Cast (defined at :48) ]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_79115]
>
> Function call stack: train_function

I have tried checking my data samples, it does not contain any string values.

Comment: Are you certain that all values in your arrays are numeric?

Comment: Please check the types of your array elements.  It seems that at least one is a string, and that your internal processes are assuming float.  Most of these routines expect you to cleanse the input data; you'll have to convert to float before calling.

Comment: Thanks, I got the issue. The string was not converted to float @pavel@prune

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run a check on your arrays to see where you might have a string value. Do something like (if `arr` is your array):

```
q = []   
for i in arr:
    try:
        q.append(np.float(i))
    except ValueError as e:
        q.append(np.nan)
baz = np.where(np.isnan(q))
```